# Getting details of remote EJB exception

Tags: ejb-3.0

I am having big problems in fetching exception details from Remote EJBs...

I have a pipeline pattern implemented with Remote EJBs, where one EJB calls other EJBs to do certain tasks. What I can't figure out is how to get more meaningful exceptions when some problem occures.

Here is an example of a "very useful" output I typically get from the EJB container (Glassfish):

`2010-11-18 12:22:36,974 DEBUG [CustomerDetectionFilter.java:48 [eef819a4debb613d0670dab35c39] - Checking customer details ...

2010-11-18 12:22:37,026 ERROR [ServiceCore.java:104] [eef819a4debb613d0670dab35c39] - nested exception is: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
        java.rmi.RemoteException: null; nested exception is: 
        javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: CORBA TRANSACTION_ROLLEDBACK 9998 Maybe; nested exception is: 
        org.omg.CORBA.TRANSACTION_ROLLEDBACK:   vmcid: 0x2000  minor code: 1806 completed: Maybe
javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
        java.rmi.RemoteException: null; nested exception is: 
        javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: CORBA TRANSACTION_ROLLEDBACK 9998 Maybe; nested exception is: 
        org.omg.CORBA.TRANSACTION_ROLLEDBACK:   vmcid: 0x2000  minor code: 1806 completed: Maybe
        at com.my.remote._CustomerDetectionFilterRemote_Wrapper.execute(com/my/remote/_CustomerDetectionFilterRemote_Wrapper.java) ~[project-common.jar:na]`

So in this case I would know that this is the cause:
java.rmi.RemoteException: null

... but I have no way of getting more useful information for debugging.

Can you recommend a way of excepting handling where the caller of remote EJB needs to get more details about the problem that occured? AppServer is Glassfish 2.1.

Thank you,

Bozo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways for handling exceptions. We can configure them to get most information about root cause from it.

Below link might provide useful information & topic is discussed briefly.

**Best practices in EJB exception handling** - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ejbexcept.html

Comment: I have again visited the link but got no problem with it, working fine http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ejbexcept.html. If still problem exists, then you can find that topic in best practices series at IBM Developerworks java section.